# Firebird transliteration issue: conversion from utf8 client to win1252 db server

Tags: sql, character-encoding, firebird, firebird2.5

I am facing a problem when trying to **update data** in a firebird database.
Setup is the following:

- NodeJS Server with Node-Firebird module (https://github.com/hgourvest/node-firebird) --> only allows UTF8 Charset
- Firebird Server 2.5 with WIN1252 Charset (charset must also stay the same)

My update statement:

```
           db.transaction((err, transaction) => {
        if (err) return closeDB(db, transaction, err);
        // Update one record by pk
      console.log("do update");

      const params = [];
      
        transaction.query(`UPDATE OBJEKT
        SET BEZ = 'Böckstraße'
        WHERE OB_KEY = 25984`, params, (err, _) => {
            // The code below is executed only when the number of parameters is less than 10
            if (err) return closeDB(db, transaction, err);
 transaction.query('select * from OBJEKT where OB_KEY = 12345', [1], (err, data) => {
                if (err) return closeDB(db, transaction, err);
                console.log(data);
                // Finally simply commit the transaction
                closeDB(db, transaction, err);
            });
        });
    });
```

When doing the update queries, I am receiving "Cannot transliterate character between charsets" error.
When I introduce the variable with my target charset (_win1252) the update is working, but the characters are not correct: Bockstraße ends up as:
[image]

I started playing around with the collations, but yet no success. How can I map these 2 charsets correctly?

Comment: There is no such thing as "server charset"! There is a charset of column(field), which may be (or not be) inherited from the database default charset. Then there is connection charset. See the https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=1462 - switch the right pane into "comments" and read the discussion there, including queries to diagnose. I suspect you failed to set connection's charset but not sure.

Comment: Also, please do NOT use string splicing! https://www.bobby-tables.com your `'Böckstraße'` should be query PARAMETER an d should not be contined within the query text itself. Same better be for `25984` but integer constants are usually hard to screw. With text, data and other not so simplistic data it is easy. Don't do splicing, use parameters.

Comment: What is the character set of the column? This can happen if you attempt to store WIN1252 bytes in a column with character set NONE and then try to read it back as UTF-8, or vice versa. A column must have an explicit character set for the server to be able to convert from and to the connection character set.

Comment: Also using introducers makes no sense here, because it is basically an instruction to the Firebird parser to interpret the bytes in the string literal in the specified character set, it is not a cast, so given the actual bytes are UTF-8 bytes, you get mojibake. You could try `CAST('Böckstraße' as VARCHAR(100) character set WIN252)` as a workaround, but the better solution is to ensure your columns have an explicit character set (and make sure that you are actually specifying a connection character set).

Comment: The character set of the column is WIN1252, same as the default character set of the database.

Comment: The connection character set is default to UTF8, as the Node-Firebird module only allows this one.

Comment: That could mean that your client is using character set NONE as the connection character set, not UTF8, but that would not explain the "cannot transliterate character between charsets" error (unless this driver itself reuses that error message for encoding errors).

Comment: I would recommend that you provide a full [mre] so that we can reproduce this and identify exactly where the error is, or you could try to report this as a bug to the maintainer of the driver.

Comment: The error message is coming from the database server, not the client itself.

Comment: @DWOME How do you know it is reported by the server and not by the driver itself?

Comment: I receive it as a callback from the server. The driver would throw the message in a driver class.

Comment: I managed to get it working by sending the data as hex-encoded, as described here:
https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-hexbinstrings.html

Comment: that would still make sense to query the server abot connection charset actually used. Because while yo do EXPECT that the library tried and succeeded to set UTF8 that was merely expectation. Bugs happen, in the library, in the server's computer, anywhere. So it generally does not harm to actually check if what should happen had really took place.

Comment: @DWOME Sending your strings hex encoded is a workaround at best, not a solution.